# get the type of a column from native Query Jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I'm migrate from EclipseLink to Hibernate

The problem is identify the types of result, or cast and assign a letter F = Dates, S = String, N = Number

```
String table = /*variable*/ 

 String sentencia = "SELECT * FROM " + table + where;
                                
          
            Vector registrosRS = 
                session.executeSelectingCall(new SQLCall(sentencia));        
         
            for (int i = 0; i < registrosRS.size(); i++) {
                Record registro = (Record)registrosRS.get(i);

                for (Iterator iterator = registro.entrySet().iterator(); 
                     iterator.hasNext(); ) {
                    Map.Entry columna = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
                    DatabaseField campo = (DatabaseField)columna.getKey();
                  
                    if (i == 0) {
                       
                       nombreCol = campo.getName();
                       String type =  define(campo);
                        definiciones.put(nombreCol, type);
                    }

            }
```

DatabaseField is a class from EclipseLink  and let check the Type

```
public String define(DatabaseField campo) {

        _log.debug("JDBC Type java: " + JDBCType.valueOf(campo.getSqlType()));
        if (JDBCType.valueOf(campo.getSqlType()).equals(JDBCType.TIMESTAMP) ||
                JDBCType.valueOf(campo.getSqlType()).equals(JDBCType.TIME) ||
                JDBCType.valueOf(campo.getSqlType()).equals(JDBCType.TIME_WITH_TIMEZONE) ||
                JDBCType.valueOf(campo.getSqlType()).equals(JDBCType.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE) ||
                JDBCType.valueOf(campo.getSqlType()).equals(JDBCType.DATE)) {
            return "F";
        } else if (JDBCType.valueOf(campo.getSqlType()).equals(JDBCType.NUMERIC) ||
                JDBCType.valueOf(campo.getSqlType()).equals(JDBCType.DECIMAL) ||
                JDBCType.valueOf(campo.getSqlType()).equals(JDBCType.BIGINT) ||
                JDBCType.valueOf(campo.getSqlType()).equals(JDBCType.TINYINT) ||
                JDBCType.valueOf(campo.getSqlType()).equals(JDBCType.SMALLINT) ||
                JDBCType.valueOf(campo.getSqlType()).equals(JDBCType.DOUBLE) ||
                JDBCType.valueOf(campo.getSqlType()).equals(JDBCType.FLOAT)) {
          return "N";
        } else if (JDBCType.valueOf(campo.getSqlType()).equals(JDBCType.VARCHAR) ||
                JDBCType.valueOf(campo.getSqlType()).equals(JDBCType.NVARCHAR) ||
                JDBCType.valueOf(campo.getSqlType()).equals(JDBCType.CHAR) ||
                JDBCType.valueOf(campo.getSqlType()).equals(JDBCType.LONGVARCHAR)) {
           return "C";
        } else {
            _log.error("Capturo tipo no especificado: " + campo.getSqlType() + " - " + campo.getName());
        }


   }
```

I tried but i dont found any alternative in Hibernate

Answer (score 0):

In Hibernate you could check the java class.
Assuming the SQL returns just one column:

```
String sql = "select column1 from ... ";
List<Object> resultList = em.createNativeQuery(sql).getResultList();
for (Object result : resultList) {
   if (result instanceof String ) {
      // Do something with a String
   } else if ( result instanceof Number ) {
      // Do something with a Number
   } else if ( result instanceof Date ) {
      // Do something with a date
   } else ...   
}
```

If you have multiple columns, it will be a `List<Object[]>`.

Unless you need the exact column type, it's probably easier than checking each possible sql type.

Comment: I tried this method, but you first need to identify the types of objects that return jdbc and Jpa implementation. Until today, its the best way to I have found