# hibernate get datatype of column native query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

i need to recover the datatype of result, after execute a dynamic native query, and make a relationship to java.sql.type

```
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sentencia);
            
    NativeQueryImpl nativeQuery = (NativeQueryImpl) query;
        
    List<Map<String, Object>> result = nativeQuery.getResultList();
          
        
    if(  result.getValue().equals(JDBCType.LONGVARCHAR)) {
    // make something 
    }
```

JDBCType is imported java.sql.JDBCType;

Comment: What query are you running? Why do you need the JDBCType? Hibernate doesn't return the  JDBCType, it will return a String or a char. Also, it should be ` List<Object[]> result`. Why do you need the

Comment: Looks like you just reworded https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74453053/get-the-type-of-a-column-from-native-query-jpa . The behavior you are looking for is not part of JPA, as JPA assumes you know the java types already from the entities that are mapped, and you should know the JDBC types expected from the database schema. If this is dynamic, you may have to resort to direct JDBC access to run the query and get what you need, same as EclipseLink was doing for you (it is open source, so you can trace through what it does for the query your are migrating)

Comment: @DavideD'Alto i need it, because that is a process like extract, transform and load, i  dont know the typing of the data, the [code is this one]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74453053/get-the-type-of-a-column-from-native-query-jpa), and how you can see is a "select * from  RandomTable", and by that is too hard build a Entity class for each class , so i nedd an alternative to get the type for each column, ( also some times there a  "select  a AS "new_column, * from randomTable", where  new column could be a subquery o function" ,

Comment: You can run a native query, get a List<Object[]>, and for each element do an instance of (String and Number, might cover most cases).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do with Hibernate is something like this:

```
List<Object[]>> results = em.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery).getResultList();
for ( Object[] row : results) {
   if ( row[0] instanceof String ) {
       String value = (String) row;
       // ... 
   } else if (row[0] instanceof Number) {
       Long value = ((Number) row[0]).longValue();
       // ...
   } else if (row[0] instanceof Date ) {
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

Depending on the SQL query you are running Hibernate will return `List<Object[]>`, if the query results has multiple columns, or `List<Object>`, if the select clause has only one column.